# bean1has a list<bean2>.Based on a property field value of bean2 filter out the list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
class Bean1{
    private int a;
    private List<Bean2> b;

    // getter and setter methods..
}

class Bean2 {
   private int id;

   // getter and setter methods..
}
```

suppose i have a `List<Bean1>`, say `bean1list`. I want to get a new `List<Bean1>` such that id of bean2 is not equal to 0.

i want to do this in java 8.

i have tried the below

```
bean1list.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> x.getB().stream())
        .filter(y -> y.getId() != 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this is returning a list of type Bean2.What i need is list of type Bean1 itself.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You want those Bean1s in the list that never had a Bean2s with id = 0 in their list?

Comment: I want to get a new List<Bean1> such that id property of bean2 is not equal to 0.All those bean2 having id !=0

Comment: So you want to modify the `List<Bean2>` for each Bean1 in the list? meaning remove those Bean2 for every Bean1 whose id is 0 or you want to remove the Bean1s itself as per YCF_L's answer?

Comment: i want to get a new list<bean1> such that list<bean2> should contain only id!=0

Answer (score 1):

> i want to get a new list such that list should contain
>   only id!=0

From your comments if you want to modify the `List<Bean2>` in each of your `Bean1` objects in the `bean1List` such that the `Bean2`s having id as 0 are removed and only `Bean2`s with non-zero ids are retained for each `Bean1` then the solution could be as follows:

```
 bean1List.forEach(bean1 -> bean1.getList().removeIf(bean2 -> bean2.getId() ==0));
```

Here for every `Bean1` using `Collection#forEach` the `List<Bean2>` is filtered out with only those `Bean2`s with non-zero ids.

The difference here is the output will have all `Bean1`s but the `Bean1`s will have their `List<Bean2>` filtered using `Collection#removeIf`.